# How to read my excel file by choosing the column of the file according to my choice

Tags: shiny

I would like to know how to read my excel file by choosing the column of the file according to my choice in Rshiny

I want to be able to choose the glue of my choice to catograph with the tmap library on a shapfile basemap with the shp extension.